# Fetch @ClassbBridge field values

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I have created an application based on Spring Data JPA and Hibernate Search. In my indexed entity I have created a ClassBridge which adds an extra field depending on the entity, but I don't know how to get this extra field.

here is my entity :

```
@Indexed
@ClassBridge(name="Image_url",
impl = ImageUrlClassBridge.class)
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCTS")
public class ProductModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Field(analyzer=@Analyzer(definition="ngram"))
    private String name;
...
}
```

here is my classBridge :

```
public class ImageUrlClassBridge implements FieldBridge,ParameterizedBridge {

    private  ProductsService productsService;



    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        ProductModel product=(ProductModel) value;
        productsService=ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(ProductsService.class);
        ImageModel image=productsService.findImageByProduct(product.getId());

        if(!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(image)){
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("\nIMAGE FOUND : "+image.getId() );
            Field field = new Field( name,image.getUrl(), luceneOptions.getStore(),
                    luceneOptions.getIndex(), luceneOptions.getTermVector() );
                    field.setBoost( luceneOptions.getBoost() );
                    document.add( field );
            }
        }
...
}
```

and here is the search method on product model:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<ProductModel> search(String keyword) {
    FullTextEntityManager ftem = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = ftem.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(ProductModel.class).get();
    Query query =queryBuilder.keyword().onField("name").matching(keyword).createQuery();
    FullTextQuery jpaQuery =ftem.createFullTextQuery(query, ProductModel.class);
    List<ProductModel> results = jpaQuery.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the field to your document using the default name (the name passed in the name parameter of the set method) so your field has the name you specified in the ClassBridge annotation (ie "Image_url").

Just use this field name in your search query.

If you want to fetch it, you have to use projections:

```
FullTextQuery jpaQuery = ftem.createFullTextQuery(query, ProductModel.class);
jpaQuery.setProjection( FullTextQuery.THIS, "Image_url" );
List results = jpaQuery.list();
Object[] firstResult = (Object[]) results.get(0);
ProductModel productModel = firstResult[0];
String imageUrl = firstResult[1];
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html/search-query.html#projections for reference.

Comment: I dont want to search with that field but I want to fetch its value

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: why does it throw me this exception : `Projecting an unstored field: Image_url`. ... note that I have done the indextion and it was done succesfuly

Comment: Well, the error message says it all: you need to store the field in the index to be able to project it. Add store = Store.YES to your @ClassBridge annotation.